# Easiest way to validate user in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need a stored procedure that can check to see if, on a login attempt, whether or not they are a valid user by sending the `login` and `password` to see if they match in the database.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: sure. just write the sproc. ideally you should salt+hash the password

Comment: Is there a user table in the database which you want to use to validate the supplied login and password, or do you want to check them against the database's own valid logins?

Comment: I have the code that is salting+hashing the password.  However, I'm fairly new to sql as far as doing anything more advanced than SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE/etc. I know how to send the input parameters into the stored procedure, but I'm not sure how to compare both of them to each field to see if I can get an exact match.  I also don't know how to send a true/false back from the stored procedure.  I apologize if these are fairly common and simple to do.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure to do this? IMHO, this *should* be implemented outside the database unless there is a special case that we don't know of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without more information the best I can offer for the moment is:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE CheckPassword
    @username VARCHAR(20),
    @password varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)
    SELECT 'true' AS UserExists
ELSE
    SELECT 'false' AS UserExists

END
```

Query amended based on your response - this will return the string 'true' or 'false' you could replace them with bit values 1 and 0 respectively if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry, I just need it to return `true` if there is a record where the `username` and `password` match.  Would I use a Case statement?  If Statement?

Comment: For that, I believe you could just add ' AND '@'username = '@'password' to the SELECT statement in the if clause.  (Had to put 's around the @ symbols as SO wouldn't allow me to make the comment without them)

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckPassword
    @username VARCHAR(20),
    @password varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM usertable WHERE userName=@username AND password=@password)
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create proc usp_ValidateStoreKeeperLogin 
@SalesmanCode VARCHAR(50)
,@LogisticUserCode VARCHAR(50)
,@LogisticUserPassword VARCHAR(50)

AS 
BEGIN

if EXISTS(select 1 from tblUser where Code=@LogisticUserCode And [password]=@LogisticUserPassword  )
SELECT '1234' SalesmanCode,'12345' LogisticUserCode,'12346' DistributorCode,1 as ReturnValue,'Success' AS Msg from tblUser

select 'INVALID USER CODE' AS Msg ,-1 as ReturnValue


END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
go
CREATE PROC usp_ValidateUser
( @userName VARCHAR(50),
    @password VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
begin
declare @credentials TABLE(
    username varchar(50),
    userPassword varchar(50)
)

SELECT null,
    CASE WHEN NombreUsuario = 'korn' and PasswordUsuario = HASHBYTES('sha1', '1234') THEN  cast(1 as bit)
        ELSE   cast(0 as bit) end as TieneAcceso

FROM Usuarios;
end
```

Comment: no le pongas mente a los parametros solo remplazalos, y la variable de tabla solo es un ejemplpo por si te sirve

Answer (score -2):

```
Create procedure validate_data

@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(20)

As 
Begin 
  If exists (select * from employee where username=@username and password=@password)
  Raiserror('Exists'16,1)
Else 
  Raiserror('Not Exists'16,1)
End
```

Here I take employee as table and username and password has the employee tables .

Comment: Why don't you do `select 0` and `select 1` instead?