# Best practices for creating authentication logic for cross-platform mobile app

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, authentication

I am trying to develop a little cross-platform using Xamarin for Visual Studio (2015) which basically reads fields from a SQL Server database and arrange them on a simple UI.

The database has only got one table, *Users*, with some columns for user information, plus two of them containing the username and password that the user should utilize to login and see its information.

I thought of implementing a simple SQL query using the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class in a similar fashion:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Users
WHERE Username = @username AND Password = @password
```

Or maybe calling a procedure like these
[Easiest way to validate user in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895039/easiest-way-to-validate-user-in-stored-procedure)
with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

...and then storing, if the login happened, the fields in some variables and then link them to the text boxes on the interface.

I don't know if this is the proper way to do it and it looks like I can't even implement a REST service for the login since there is only one "master" user which can access the database itself.

The first problem I see with the above logic is how can I check if the user has already logged in, if too much time has passed, without a session or a token?

My question is, does somebody have some good tutorials and guides to study, maybe with some good examples, so I can address this authentication/login difficulty?

(Sorry for any mistake, I am new to this topic and would like to learn)

Comment: Hello Rob, I am not sure if I quite understood your question, but I store username and password so, if the user "already exists", he can login with his credentials, since the users already exist in the database.

Comment: Dont need to invent the wheel. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/

Comment: Hello Dany, as far as I understand the method you posted uses a third party provider for the authentication, I already have users and passwords on my database and that should be the only way to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really best practice for this. Firstly, you are doing the right thing by parameterizing your SQL query. You do need to make sure there are no SQL injection attacks. But basically the way you authenticate is up to you. You can look in to oAuth if you want to use the industry standard for logging in over web sites.

But in your case, you may want to simply keep a static dictionary of usernames by tokens. So when a user logs in, simply add a guid to a dictionary and give that guid to the user. Then, on subsequent calls, you will know who the user is because they will pass the token to you on each call. Just make sure you expire the tokens by removing them from the dictionary after say 24 hours.

*Just a caveat on the above. I didn't meant that there are no best practice recommendations for authentication. I just meant that authentication itself can be done in any number of ways, and that because you already have a "Users" table, it seems as though you want authentication to be driven by this.*

*Here is a good [article](https://www.techsling.com/2017/08/best-practices-secure-mobile-app-authentication/) on authentication and security for good measure. There are other measures like multi factor authentication that can be added to an existing authentication scheme to increase security.*